# SSRS 2008 R2 on Server 2008 XML Data extension error

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an MVC 3 project that shows soem reports through SSRS.  I have everythign set up on a Windows 7 computer and it works fine.  We just installed Server 2008 on a new computer and I am trygin to get everythign running through IIS.  Everythign works fine except for the Data Source that I use for the reports.  I have it grabbing XML data from a Web Service to show in the report.  When I deploy all the report information to the Server 2008 SQL instance I get the following error when I look at the Data Source.

The data processing extension used for this report is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly.

If I lookin the Data Source Type dropdown the only option is SQL Server.  XML is not listed.  What do I need to do.  From what I read XML was supposed to be supported automatically without any setup.

Comment: As long as this is not the express edition this should work. Find and locate this file RSReportServcer.config.  Ensure that the assembly and references it uses are correct per the version of SQL Server you are using.  A small google search yields this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jenss/archive/2009/10/26/ssis-as-a-data-source-needed-watch-out-for-configuration-traps.aspx , it is not for XML but closely related.

Comment: I am using the express version

Comment: ohh well that explains it.  I was going to say it worked on my other computer but I now remember I upgraded to the developer version on my other computer.  Thanks for the info.  Write it in a reply and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server express does not support XML.
(See also notes in the comments section)